# Why $C$ is not a simple curve?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, curves

The definition for a simple curve according to Stewart, Calculus Early Transcendental (9th edition) is:

A curve that does not intersect itself anywhere between its endpoints.

But then the book said on pg.1158 that $C$ in fig.8 is a simple curve and that the y axis diivides it into 2 simple curves, could someone explain to me why it is not a simple curve according to the given definition please?

Here is the figure below:

> [image]

Comment: The text claims that $D$ (rather than $C$) is not simple. How does Stewart define a simple region?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos ok, so you are defferentiating between a simple region and a simple curve. right?